# Resetting a field lazy-loaded with the double-check idiom

Tags: java, thread-safety, locking, double-checked-locking

Consider the "double-check idiom for lazy initialization of instance fields":

> ```
> // Item 71 in Effective Java copied from this interview with Bloch.
> private volatile FieldType field;
> FieldType getField() {
>     FieldType result = field;
>     if (result == null) { // First check (no locking)
>         synchronized(this) {
>             result = field;
>             if (result == null) // Second check (with locking)
>                 field = result = computeFieldValue();
>         }
>     }
>      return result;
> }
> ```

I want to be able to reset the field in a safe way (force it to load again from the database, in my case). I assume that we could do this by having a reset method:

> ```
> void reset() {
>    field = null;
> }
> ```

Is this the standard way of doing resetting the field? Is it safe? Any pitfalls? I'm asking because Bloch gave the following warning about double-checked lazy-loading: "The idiom is very fast but also complicated and delicate, so don't be tempted to modify it in any way. Just copy and paste -- normally not a good idea, but appropriate here."

Thanks in advance,
Playa from the Himalayas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is thread safe.

The synchronized block is to prevent multiple threads from unnecessarily calling `computeFieldValue()`. Since `field` is volatile, the accesses in `reset` and `getField` are all well-ordered.

If the first check is non-null, `getField` is done; `result` is returned.

Otherwise, a lock is acquired, excluding any other thread that might set the field to non-null, but permitting any thread to set `field` to null. If any thread does set `field` to null, nothing should have changed; that's the condition that got the thread into the synchronized block. If another thread had already acquired the lock after the current thread's check, and set the field to a non-null value, the second check will detect that.

Answer (score 3):

I think this should be safe, but only because you're storing the field in a local variable.  After this is done, there's no way for the local variable reference to magically change to null, even if another thread is resetting field's value half-way through.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this will work as long as the reset method is the `reset()` method listed above. However, if the `reset()` method instantiates a new Object (like below), couldn't you end up potentially returning something different than you intended?

```
void reset() {
    field = new FieldType();
}
```

Comment: yes, but that type of reset would defeat the whole purpose of the double-check idiom.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it depends on exactly what you mean by thread-safe.

You could end up with a situation where a first instance is used after a second. That may be okay, or it may not.

Answer (score 0):

I think reset() method isn't correct. If you read Item 71, you'll find:

> This code may appear a bit convoluted. In particular, the need for the local
> variable result may be unclear. What this variable does is to ensure that field is
> **read only** once in the common case where it’s already initialized.

Lazy initialization does't suppose that **field** might changed. If field will be set to null between these operators:

`FieldType result = field;
if (result == null) { // First check (no locking)`

getField() provide incorrect result.